# JFrog Artifactory doesn't show dependency declaration

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I created default repository for gradle and published jar into it. I don't see snippets with dependency declaration on the JAR description page. Whats wrong?

[image: Artifactory repository browser for package with missing information]

Comment: tried the same configuration as you did, with the same Artifactory version (5.8.3) but I can see it. 
Can you clear your browser cache and try again? maybe it's a caching issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "Deploy" option at the top right-hand corner. I found that you need to define the "Layout Token" option before the Dependency Declaration shows up.

I just fill in the fields with "relevant" information but there might be a more acceptable formatting.

[image]: